# Is "Children of Men" a remake?

Tags: identify-this-movie, children-of-men

I can swear I watched a movie where the whole worlds population was sterile for some reason, and there was a woman who was pregnant so the protagonist was trying to save her and her baby. The issue is that I should have watched that movie at least 15 years ago, because I remember very vividly when I was watching *Children of Men* (in 2006) that I thought it was a remake of the old one. I checked Wikipedia, they say it is based on a book, but I am also sure I didn't read the story, I watched it.

Am I crazy or what?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a remake to have similar/nearly identical plots... Look at *Dredd* and *The Raid: Redemption*. http://screenscreener.blogspot.com/2015/05/competing-film-showdown-raid-redemption.html

Comment: An example of what @Catija has mentioned. The film Aeon Flux 2005 has a storyline that includes infertility in the worlds population.

Comment: Also similar is The Handmaids Tale 1990 :)

Comment: Could it be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019,_After_the_Fall_of_New_York ?  A group of people searching New York for the last fertile woman in a post-nuclear holocaust scenario where most of humanity has been rendered sterile.  Originally an Italian movie from 1980s, it was also aired in English in the US, apparently.

Comment: American Cyborg: Steel Warrior (1993)

Answer (score 3):

The film that you most likely saw was the 1994 direct to video "classic" ***American Cyborg: Steel Warrior***

This is for several reasons including:

1. The source novel for ***Children of Men*** was released in 1992, 2 years before American Cyborg: Steel Warrior was released on DVD. While the core narrative is the same (a world suffering from a depopulation crisis) the film and the novel diverge in narrative structure and characters. It's likely that either writer of film read the novel, or perhaps read a treatment of similar story that diverged just enough to avoid legal action from being taken.
2. Both films and the 1992 novel have a similar core elements that match that of a 1964 novel called ***Greybeard***, What is odd about the 1994 is that it is so close to the 1964 novel that legal action should have been considered if it wasn't undertaken. Either way, the core narrative (a single pregnant woman in a sterile world)

Anyway, the 1994 film was released direct to video and seems to have been a staple of late night cable fare (which is where I saw it in either 1996 or 1997) meaning that you would have ample opportunities to have viewed it. Again, while it has similar elements to Children of Men, the narratives diverge so widely beyond the core elements that they are actually different stories altogether by their endings.

Reference:
https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/dec/13/brian-aldiss-science-fiction-author-review

Comment: DVD back in 1994? What?